# Why encrypting in AES/CBC/ZeroBytePadding with Android and JavaScript returns different results for some strings?

Tags: javascript, android, encryption, aes

This is the code in JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/pad-zeropadding-min.js"></script>
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="0"></div>
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<script>

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('32_length_String');
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('32_length_String');
var message = '{"login":[{"username":"25697","passwd":"asdf"}]}';
$('#0').text("Message: "+message);

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key, { iv: iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC});
$('#1').text("Encrypted BASE64: "+encrypted);
$('#2').text("Encrypted HEX: "+encrypted.ciphertext);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the android code:

```
private static final String ZERO_PADDING_KEY = "32_length_String";
private static final String IV = "32_length_String";
private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/ZeroBytePadding";

public static String encryptAESURL(String url) {
    try {

        byte[] key = ZERO_PADDING_KEY.getBytes("UTF-8");

        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

        byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOf(IV.getBytes("UTF-8"), 16);

        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);

        // encryption pass
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks, ivspec);

        byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(url.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        String resul = bytesToHex(encryptedText);
        url = resul;
        return resul;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ENCRYPT ERROR", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        //  throw new CryptoException("Unable to decrypt", e);

    }
    return url;

    final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
```

The problem is that using the string : `{"login":[{"username":"25697","passwd":"asdf"}]}`

The JavaScript code returns the hexadecimal:

```
c88928b4542a8faa774f27670c563fdfcb8dcc8ae554d3dd05a86ac7869d91d36a170a4e093b75e2702e8374f206e7f4
```

The Android code returns the hexadecimal:

```
C88928B4542A8FAA774F27670C563FDFCB8DCC8AE554D3DD05A86AC7869D91D36A170A4E093B75E2702E8374F206E7F4DF33A2FBEE7FD2DBC1ED0430F3E45DCF
```

This two hexadecimal are similar but in the android code ads more characters at the end, encrypting others Strings like:
`{"login":[{"username":"25697","passwd":"asd"}]}`
or
`{"login":[{"username":"25697","passwd":"asdfg"}]}` returns the same hexadecimal. I can't find what is wrong in the Android code why is happening this.

Comment: I only use the first 16 bytes  byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOf(IV.getBytes("UTF-8"), 16);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Android's ZeroBytePadding which is based on BouncyCastle will always add padding, but CryptoJS will not.

AES is a block cipher and as such operates only on complete blocks of 16 bytes. CryptoJS' ZeroPadding will add only so many 0x00 bytes until a multiple of the block size is reached. Android's ZerBytePadding on the other hand will do the same, but if the plaintext is already a multiple of the block size, then it will add a complete block of 0x00 bytes.

In your case, the first plaintext is 48 bytes which means that ZeroBytePadding will add an additional block.

Android's cipher code is based on BouncyCastle and it was [discussed before](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/ZeroBytePadding-adds-spurious-blocks-td4656342.html), why BouncyCastle does it in this way. It won't be "fixed".

I suggest that you use PKCS#5/PKCS#7 padding (they're the same) which enables you to use have 0x00 bytes at the end of the plaintext which is not possible with ZeroPadding.

---

Don't forget that you should protect against manipulation of your ciphertexts by employing a message authentication code. Use for example HMAC-SHA256 over the ciphertext with a different key.

Comment: Is there any way to do it like in Javascript in android with ZeroPadding?

Comment: You could check whether `url.getBytes("UTF-8").length % 16 == 0` in which case you can simply throw away that last block: `encryptedText = Arrays.copyOf(encryptedText, encryptedText.length - 16);`. But if you want to decrypt it in Android afterwards, you probably won't be able to. Why are you so attached to ZeroPadding? PKCS5Padding is better.

Comment: My client is using ZeroPadding no my decision, thanks for the suggestion